# Mean values from a table in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, table, average

I have uploaded a table containing information on river basins within countries (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/basins/TFDD_BCU). I want to calculate the mean population density in the basins from this image:

```
var Pop1975 = ee.Image('JRC/GHSL/P2016/POP_GPW_GLOBE_V1/1975');
```

I have tried this code:

```
var BCU = ee.FeatureCollection('users/basins/TFDD_BCU');

var Pop1975mean = Pop1975.reduceRegions({
  collection: BCU,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500,
});

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(null, Pop1975mean)
  ]),
  description: 'Pop1975mean',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

When running the export to the drive the process is stopped after a short while, reporting an 'internal error' but no additional information. Is the dataset too large or is there a mistake in the code?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: When running the export to the drive after less than a minute it says:
State: Failed &
Error: Internal error

Answer (score 1):

The output of reduceRegion**s** is a feature collection, thus, this export should work:

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: Pop1975mean,
  description: 'Pop1975mean',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

By applyging reduceRegion() on the BCU, your output will be a dictionary and your Export assignment would be correct if BCU is a variable.

Hope this works, otherwise, make share a link of your code and give access to your feature collection.

Comment: It works well. Thanks a lot! But I didn't expect to have missing missing values for most observations as the image covers the whole world. I felt like this is a different problem, so I opened a new question: [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324004/missing-values-when-calculating-mean)