# Missing values when calculating mean

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, average

I have uploaded a table containing information on river basins within countries (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/basins/TFDD_BCU). I want to calculate the mean population density in the basins from an image. However, I obtain many missing values though the image covers the whole world. Is there a way to obtain the mean for all regions?

According to Taras' and Ricacardo's proposal, I changed the code to this:

```
var Pop1975 = ee.Image('JRC/GHSL/P2016/POP_GPW_GLOBE_V1/1975');
var BCU = ee.FeatureCollection('users/basins/TFDD_BCU');

var Pop1975filtered = Pop1975.filter(ee.Filter.gt('BCU', 0));

var Pop1975mean = Pop1975filtered.reduceRegions({
  collection: BCU,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 50,
});

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: Pop1975mean,
  description: 'Pop1975mean',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

However, I get this error message when execuding the code: "Pop1975.filter is not a function".
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your mean calculation is correct but it includes 0 values. You want to mask those values first:

```
var Pop1975 = ee.Image('JRC/GHSL/P2016/POP_GPW_GLOBE_V1/1975');
var BCU = ee.FeatureCollection('users/basins/TFDD_BCU');


Map.addLayer(Pop1975.updateMask(Pop1975.neq(0))) // see all zero pixels removed.
Map.addLayer(ee.Feature(BCU.first()))

// select first feature for testing
var testCollect = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(BCU.first())) 

var Pop1975mean = Pop1975.updateMask(Pop1975.neq(0)).reduceRegions({
    collection: BCU,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 250 , // native resolution is in 250 meters according to metadata
})

print(Pop1975mean, 'Pop1975mean')

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: Pop1975mean,
  description: 'Pop1975mean',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not used to working with EE but why not creating a prefiltered feature collection for pixels with a valid measurement  (pseudo code, not tested):
// Filter to get only valid numbers if 'BCU' is your attribute of choice.

```
var Pop1975filtered = Pop1975.filter(ee.Filter.gt('BCU', 0));
```

Comment: This does not work as "Pop1975" is an image. I tried this:
`var Pop1975filtered = Pop1975.gte(0);`
But this also not the solution. The values are still missing and for those few observations that are not missing I now get a 1.

Comment: updateMask is required. .gte is a boolean operator and returns 0 (not greater than 0) or 1 (greater than 0).